# how to pass object variable in a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, ssis

I am storing my table as a result set from a execute sql task in a variable (i.e. @varTableData)
Which is having 5 columns (i.e. result from a select statement)

Now, I want to insert these five records to other table for which I want to pass this variable to a stored procedure and just insert all these columns data to the other table.

How can I do that ? I mean, is it possible to have a complete vobject in a stored procedure variable and I can directly insert that. Or there can be better way to implement the same

Comment: The quick (untested) answer is no, the SSIS object type is fairly useless outside of a few tasks (script, foreach enumerator). 2008 does allow for the creation of user defined table types which allow you to pass tables as parameters to procedures. [Blog post on the subject](http://billfellows.blogspot.com/2010/06/t-sql-tuesday-007-summertime-in-sql.html) I would be surprised if the native Execute SQL Task would allow for UDTT as parameters. I'll do some thinking about your larger question though, see what I come up with.

Comment: If the intent is just to insert those records to the other table, then just insert them from there, instead of passing it to another stored proc